# Dictionary sorting with string index and values python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort my Dictionary, by the first value after calling my index ( in this case: Company Name). My structure is like following:

### Its stored in a JSON-File:

```
{

"0": ["Microsoft", "IT", "Software", "USA", "12000"],
"1": ["Intel", "IT", "Hardware", "BELGIUM", "14500"],
"2": ["Cisco", "IT", "Hardware", "GERMANY", "45120"],
"3": ["HP", "IT", "Hardware", "GERMANY", "545612"],
"4": ["Apple", "IT", "Hardware", "GERMANY", "454555"]  

}
```

**print(mydict[str(id)[0]) shows the company name**

Type of Data in each rows as following:

> Company Name -> Business-> activity -> Country -> Amount of staff
>   employeed

If i try to sort my dictonary with sorted(mydict) it doesnt work, I also tried to sort it with zip and it failed aswell.

*Its my first time working with dictornaries and im still learning python, so i would really need a hand right there*

I want to use this sorted dictionary to fill a table which I generate with Mako-Template Engine. It works already with the unsorted dictionary :)

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries and HashTables are **unordered**, you can however use an **OrderedDict** if you want to maintain order in your data.

An OrderedDict can be created from your data

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = {

"0": ["Microsoft", "IT", "Software", "USA", "12000"],
"1": ["Intel", "IT", "Hardware", "BELGIUM", "14500"],
"2": ["Cisco", "IT", "Hardware", "GERMANY", "45120"],
"3": ["HP", "IT", "Hardware", "GERMANY", "545612"],
"4": ["Apple", "IT", "Hardware", "GERMANY", "454555"]  

}

d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x : x[1][0][0]))
#  x[1] is the value, x[1][0] is the list, x[1][0][0] is the company name
print(d)

OrderedDict([('4', ['Apple', 'IT', 'Hardware', 'GERMANY', '454555']), ('2', ['Cisco', 'IT', 'Hardware', 'GERMANY', '45120']), ('3', ['HP', 'IT', 'Hardware', 'GERMANY', '545612']), ('1', ['Intel', 'IT', 'Hardware', 'BELGIUM', '14500']), ('0', ['Microsoft', 'IT', 'Software', 'USA', '12000'])])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't 'sort' a dictionary. Dictionaries don't have order that is required if you want to sort it.

Since you just want to write it out though, you can get the *keys* sorted in the order of the names in the dictionary. Then, write the dictionary contents out based on the order of the keys returned from `sorted`.

So, ordering by name can be done:

```
# sorted(d, key=d.get) returns [4, 2, 3, 1, 0]
for i in sorted(d, key=d.get):  
    print(d[i])  # or, write it out
```

Which prints the contents out in order:

```
['Apple', 'IT', 'Hardware', 'GERMANY', '454555']
['Cisco', 'IT', 'Hardware', 'GERMANY', '45120']
['HP', 'IT', 'Hardware', 'GERMANY', '545612']
['Intel', 'IT', 'Hardware', 'BELGIUM', '14500']
['Microsoft', 'IT', 'Software', 'USA', '12000']
```

which you can, alternatively, write out.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement my own version to sort the dictionary, without using a ordered, i just made the company name into Key and used this to sort my dictionary and it worked!

```
data_companies = {}

    for key_s in data_opl:
        new_key =  data_opl[key_s][0]
        data_companies[new_key] = data_opl[key_s]
```

After that i just used this to print them out:

```
for id_s in sorted(data_companies.keys()):
    print(data_companies[id_s][0])
    print(data_companies[id_s][1])
    print(data_companies[id_s][2])
    print(data_companies[id_s][3])
    print(data_companies[id_s][4])
```

I really appreciate and value your effort of helping me